# making parameters not apllicable

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I'm using ReportBuilder 3.0, I have a 5 parameter report, the first parameter gives the option of bringing back all the data  or whether to filter.

[image]
[image]
My report basically consists of two rectangles both with a number of charts in. The 1st rectangle I have set the visibility for it to only show when the @ReportSelection parameter is selected as  'everything'.

The second rectangle will only show when @ReportSelection is set as 'Drillthrough'. The users other parameter selections come In to play with this action.

What I need is when the user selects 'Everything' I want the other parameters to be hidden (though it looks like this is not possible) or at least default to something like 'Not Applicable'.

My first parameter looks like this   - @param

[image]

The second one is based on a query  -@sdg

```
 select distinct
 sdg
 from 
 [dbo].[Table]

 where  (@param ='2' or @param = '1')

 order by 1 asc
```

Third parameter  -@la

```
 select distinct localauthority

 from(

 select distinct

 localauthority,
 sdg

 from 
 [dbo].[Table]


 )as A

 where (sdg in (@sdg) 

 and (@param ='2' or @param ='1'))

 order by 1 asc
```

Fourth parameter -@Ward

```
 select distinct ward

 from(

 select distinct
 ward,
 localauthority

from 
[dbo].[table)as A

where (localauthority in (@la)
and (@param ='2' or @param ='1'))

order by 1 asc
```

I have tried putting an expression in the default part of the parameters but it had no affect.

```
=IIF(Parameters!ReportSelection.value = "Everything" , "N/A")," "")
```

This is the best description I've found on how to do it but I'm struggling to implement it in to mine.

```
https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-creat-multi-option-parameter-report-in-sql
```

Comment: I **think** you'll have to make the other parameters' values based on a query, and those queries have to be based on the parameter @ReportSelection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to sort this eventually at the cost of 50 reputation, oh well. Created a Union in each of my parameters with an 'Everything' field.  Then set the default values for all the parameters to 'Everything'.  It's far from perfect but It will do the job

```
select * from(


select distinct localauthority

from(

select distinct

localauthority,
sdg

from 
[dbo].[Table]

union all

select distinct

'Everything' as localauthority,
'Everything' as sdg

from 
[dbo].[Table]

)as A



where (sdg = @sdg

and (@param ='2' or @param ='1'))

and localauthority <> 'Unknown'


)as D

order by 1 asc
```